# RegExp to find tag and variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, replace

Can you please correct my RegExp so it will work? I need to check if the string I want to replace is not surrounded by an a tag.

```
var re = new RegExp("<a\b[^>]*>"+variable+"<\/a>","gi");
```

Comment: How are you implementing this? Do you want to say `if(str.match(regex) == null)`

Comment: Exactly. Actually i want to see if it's not null. So if(str.match(regex) != null)

Comment: But your code matches `variable` in an anchor tag, and you said you wanted to check if a string is not surrounded by an `a` tag. Your attempted regex would return null if `variable` is not surrounded by an `a` tag

Comment: I want the match to return null if it finds the variable already surrounded by the a tag. If it's not surrounded yet, i want to replace it with an a tag identified by a uniqid

Answer (score 1):

You must capture all links before and replace them by themselves:

```
var variable = "os";
var yourstring= "sdfsdlkjfsd <a href=blux> os</a> sdfsdflkjsdf os";

var re = new RegExp("(<a\\b[^>]*>(?:[^<]+|<(?!/a>))*</a>)|("+variable+")","gi");

function replacer(match, p1, p2){
    var replacement = "glups";
    return (p1)? p1 : replacement;
};
var result = yourstring.replace(re, replacer);
console.log(result);
```

Pattern detail:

`(?:[^<]+|<(?!/a>))*` describes the content between "a" tags, and means *all that is not a `<` or a `<` that is not the part of the closing "a" tag*

```
(?:          # open a non capturing group
    [^<]+    # all characters except < one or more times
  |          # OR
    <(?!/a>) # < not followed by "/a>"
)*           # close the non capturing group and repeat zero or more times
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to double up the backslash in `\\b` so it makes it through to the regular expression as `\b`:

```
var re = new RegExp("<a\\b[^>]*>"+variable+"<\/a>","gi");
```